# Distribute tasks between multiple instance of application using NestJs and k8s

Tags: kubernetes, nestjs, scheduled-tasks

I have a cron job which runs for every 3 seconds and we have 3 instances(3 k8s pods) running for this. So when ever the job runs I need to query a list of unprocessed records and then publish them to kafka topic. I am trying to implement a process which equally distributes the result set equally to each instance running on k8s. Can someone advise how can we achieve this using @nestjs/schedule. Thanks.

Comment: `@nestjs/schedule` will run in parallel in each app, meaning you will be running the job 3 times every 3 seconds. You could implement some sort of logic to spread the runs across different instances, but it would be easier to let k8s handle the load balancing. I would suggest using k8s Cronjobs or NestJS Queues with a repeating job (see RepeatOpts). This answer provides good info on strategies for handling this type of issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70185956/735398